# Making Python 3.X program exit when the escape key is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just messing around with a simple program like:

```
    import random
    game = True
    body = ['right foot', 'left foot', 'right hand', 'left hand']
    color = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
    while game:
        userinput = input('What would you like to do?')
        if userinput == '':
            random1 = random.choice(body)
            random2 = random.choice(color)
        print(random1 + ' ' + random2)
    if userinput == 'quit':
        game = False
```

I was wondering, instead of having the user type in quit, how could I make is so that the program quits when the escape key is pressed?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Hmm...you could use `try...except` to catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` error. Which will raise when user press Ctrl+C.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user